# Is there a formal/better word than "skyrocket" for the given context?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> The labour market condition in a region where the unemployment rate skyrocketed from 6 to 10 percent is no better than in the region where the rate fell from 13 to 12 percent.

I can't find a word that fits there except "skyrocketed". "Soared" or "surged" does not work there for some reason. It just does not sound right to my ears.

I am happy with how skyrocketed sounds, but the word is informal. And I am writing an academic paper.

Comment: What makes you think skyrocketing is inappropriate for an academic paper? It's frequently used in economic research papers, for example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both "soared" and "surge" work perfectly fine in this context.  Perhaps they don't sound right to you because you've never heard them properly used.  Some examples:

> [6 Metrics Behind Zoom Video's **Soaring** Stock Price](https://www.fool.com/investing/2019/06/08/6-metrics-behind-zoom-videos-soaring-stock-price.aspx)
>
> [The last time rates **soared** like this, the stock market plunged double-digits](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/10/05/last-time-rates-soared-like-this-stock-market-plunged-double-digits.html)

and in the same story:

> Interest rates are **surging** in the U.S. and around the world, sending shock waves through equity markets

Figurative synonyms such as *rocketed*, *shot up*, *swelled*, and others are also common.

If you don't want to use figurative language -- and there is no reason why you shouldn't, even in an academic paper -- then *rose sharply* or *increased rapidly* both work. Example:

> [Report: US electricity prices rose sharply in October](https://www.ogj.com/home/article/17264184/report-us-electricity-prices-rose-sharply-in-october)

In the future, try doing a Google search on a particular word combination such as "rate surge" before assuming it is not idiomatic.  You might find that it's actually quite common.

Comment: I'd say "surge" would be better. "soared" has a positive connotation to my ear (as a native AmE speaker), and increasing unemployment rates are certainly not positive.

Comment: @Hearth  I wouldn't, but it's good to know different people have different interpretations of its nuance.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to suggest that **[skyrocketing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skyrocket)** is actually your best option.

The concern seems to be that "skyrocketing" is too informal for use in academic writing. I don't believe this is really true.

It's easy to find [examples](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C10&q=skyrocketing&btnG=) of scholarly research using this word, in both social sciences and [physical sciences](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.omicsonline.org%20skyrocket), and it seems to be especially common in [economics](https://admin.nber.org/xsearch?q=skyrocket).

It is a much stronger word than surge, or even soar, implying an extremely large increase over a very short period of time. It's most commonly associated with rising prices or rising rates of occurrence.

While many of the things the word is applied to are considered undesirable, I believe the word itself is essentially neutral in tone. While it's [most commonly used with undesirables like inflation, prices, and costs](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skyrocketing%20rates%2Cskyrocketing%20inflation%2Cskyrocketing%20costs%2Cskyrocketing%20interest%2Cskyrocketing%20prices%2Cskyrocketing%20demand%2Cskyrocketing%20unemployment&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20rates%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20inflation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20costs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20interest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20prices%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20demand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20unemployment%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20rates%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20inflation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20costs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20interest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20prices%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20demand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskyrocketing%20unemployment%3B%2Cc0), it can be applied to desirable effects such as literacy and employment rates as well.

A good opposite word for a sudden dramatic decrease would be "plummet"

Comment: Agreed. [This report](https://books.google.com/books?id=YcmqcpglnAcC) doesn’t look like informal reading, and neither does [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=EHXRYXtQyWoC).

Comment: I think the key to using "skyrocketing" idiomatically is that it is usually applied to negative negative outcomes.  Prices, interest rates, unemployment, etc.

Comment: @BenJackson I think that is mostly a matter of context. When you're talking about things that can rapidly increase, there are lots of bad things, like inflation rates, disease, unemployment, etc. but there are also plenty of things that are neutral or positive, and in many cases its a matter of your viewpoint whether something is positive or negative. Skyrocketing oil prices? Bad for low income people who drive to work, great for owners of oil company stock, and so forth.

Comment: @Ben - You could be right about what’s “usually” the case. However, a couple counterexamples, just to show it’s not always the case: [Careers](https://www.businessinsider.com/candice-huffine-signs-with-img-2016-4) can skyrocket; so can player stats in sports: _his batting average [skyrocketed](https://www.theadvocate.com/acadiana/sports/ul_lafayette/article_fcb7dbda-71e2-11e9-b007-6395e48818a5.html) from .159 to .258._ But interestingly enough, I looked for examples of “recycling has skyrocketed” in the news. It was usually in a negative context (e.g., “The cost of recycling has skyrocketed").

Comment: Personally I think extremely rapid increases in anything are always bad for someone somewhere.

Comment: @barbecue Thanks very much, this is helpful and reassuring. In your experience, do you think it is unwise to use "skyrocketed/soared/something-dramatic" with a simple "fell" in a case such as mine where I am comparing an apple with a much bigger apple?

Comment: @AIQ - Your example sentence is fine. Because the drop is relatively small, and the increase is more dramatic, it works to use a more “colorful” word to describe the increase, and a more bland word to describe the small drop.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using *fell*, the contrasting verb (in the past tense) is simply **rose**:

From [*rise*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rise):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **7 a** : to move upward : ASCEND
>   **7 b** : to increase in height, size, volume, or pitch

Also since you are not using a dramatic version of *fell* (such as *plummeted* or *crashed*), despite the fact that the decrease was fairly small, the same neutral language seems to be appropriate for its complement.

However, if you *do* want something more dramatic, but you don't like any of the words you've mentioned, there seem to be fewer other options that you'd likely be happy with. Perhaps just using an adjective, such as *swiftly rose*, would be the most formal.

Comment: For the purpose of my topic, I need to talk about the importance of the direction and magnitude of the rate. I intended to use "fell" as the change is very small as opposed to 4% increase. I actually need the word for the "rise" to be dramatic and the word for the "fall" to be as simple as "fell".

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have set yourself two contradictory requirements. You want a dramatic, emotive, journalistic term like "skyrocket", or "surge", but also a term suitable for an academic paper, which should not be dramatic or emotive but descriptive or analytic,  plain and simple.

So either you choose an unemotive term like "rose", "increased" or you use a journalistic term like "surged", you can't have both.

Comment: yes I see that now, I was hoping for something that would be both, but in this case it does not seem like one exists that is both academic and dramatic.

Answer (score 2):

You could say *jumped* to indicate a rise over an unusually short time period.

From [jump](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jump):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 b** : to move suddenly or involuntarily
>   **2 a** : to move haphazardly or irregularly : shift abruptly
>   **2 b** : to undergo a sudden sharp change in value